# Replace strings from left until the first occuring string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

I am trying to figure out how to replace example:

sw1_code1_number1_jpg      --> code1_number1_jpg
hon2_noncode_number2_jpg   --> noncode_number2_jpg
ccc3_etccode_number3_jpg   --> etccode_number3_jpg
ddd4_varcode_number4_jpg   --> varcode_number4_jpg

So the results are all string after the first _
If it doesn't find any _ then do nothing.

I know how to find and replace strings, str.replace, indexof, lastindexof but dont know how remove up to the first found occurrence.

Thank You

Comment: Take a look at the `slice` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with a regular expression:

```
"sw1_code1_number1_jpg".replace(/^.*?_/, "");
```

Comment: Consider this modified regex: `/^.*?_/` in the event the string begins with a `_`.

Comment: To the OP: Do note the importance of the `?` metacharacter being used for non-greedy matching - `.*?` does not do something like `(.*)?`, these are entirely different uses.

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches you can take:

```
var str = 'sw1_code1_number1_jpg';
var arr = str.split('_');
arr.shift();
var newSfr = arr.join('_');
```

Or you could use slice or replace:

```
var str = 'sw1_code1_number1_jpg';
var newStr = str.slice(str.indexOf('_')+1);
```

Or

```
var newStr = 'sw1_code1_number1_jpg'.replace(/^[^_]+_/,'');
```

Comment: The slice demo doesn't work with other examples than the one you gave because it doesn't search for an index of '_'

Comment: I don't mean to be annoying but you should add one to the result of indexOf as you don't want to include the underscore

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thanks for bearing with my mistakes. ---- +1

Comment: waw it works great.
Thank you all for your responses, it really helped me to reach the task. Just super super help.

Comment: @ErjonG. Glad I could be of some help. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

You could split your string and get a `slice`

```
var str = 'sw1_code1_number1_jpg';
var finalStr = str.split('_').slice(1).join('_') || str;
```

If your original string does not contain an underscore, then it returns the original string.

---

**UPDATE** A simpler one with `slice` (still works with strings not containing underscores)

```
var str = 'sw1_code1_number1_jpg';
var finalStr = str.slice(str.indexOf('_') + 1);
```

This one works in all cases because when no underscore is found, `-1` is returned and as we add 1 to the index we call `str.slice(0)` which is equal to str.